# Android spinner with objects

Tags: java, android, object

I have an async task which populates a spinner with data. The spinner data comes from objects in a list. My problem is when I set the onclick listener for the items in the list I also want the id from the object not just the name:

```
public class PortfolioGetAllLists extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener useThis;

    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public PortfolioGetAllLists (Context context, PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener thisListener)
    {
        c = context;
        useThis = thisListener;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting Brewery List");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            final ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.allYourBeersList);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<String> tasteList = new ArrayList<String>();


            tasteList.add("");
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String bID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                String beer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                String rate = "na";
                String beerID = "na";


                //create object
                ShortBeerInfo tempTaste = new ShortBeerInfo(beer, rate, beerID, bID);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(beer);
            }


            // Selection of the spinner
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);

            // Application of the Array to the Spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tasteList );
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            //add on item selected
            final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);
            portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                    String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    //Toast.makeText(((Activity) c).getApplicationContext(), portfolioChoice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    lv.setAdapter(null);

                    //get brewery beers
                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);



                    try {

                        portfolioChoice = URLEncoder.encode(portfolioChoice, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //construct url
                    String url = "myURL";

                    Log.d("portfolio", url);
                    //async task goes here
                    //new PortfolioGetAllBeers(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                    PortfolioGetAllBeers task = new PortfolioGetAllBeers(c);
                    task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(useThis);
                    task.execute(url);

                }



                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    // do nothing
                }

            });



        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

This line below is the line which get the beers name, but I do not know how to get also the id from the object which sets the listview name:

```
String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

**`Update:`**

I have changed my above code to this to incorporate a custom adapter:

```
public class PortfolioGetAllLists extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener useThis;

    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public PortfolioGetAllLists (Context context, PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener thisListener)
    {
        c = context;
        useThis = thisListener;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting Brewery List");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            final ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.allYourBeersList);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<ShortBeerInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<ShortBeerInfo>();


            //tasteList.add("");
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String bID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                String beer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                String rate = "na";
                String beerID = "na";


                //create object
                ShortBeerInfo tempTaste = new ShortBeerInfo(beer, rate, beerID, bID);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);
            }


            // Selection of the spinner
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);

            // Application of the Array to the Spinner
            ShortBeerInfoAdapter<ShortBeerInfo> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ShortBeerInfo>(c,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tasteList );
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            //add on item selected
            final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);
            portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                    String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();


                    //Toast.makeText(((Activity) c).getApplicationContext(), portfolioChoice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    lv.setAdapter(null);

                    //get brewery beers
                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);



                    try {

                        portfolioChoice = URLEncoder.encode(portfolioChoice, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //construct url
                    String url = "myURL";    
                    Log.d("portfolio", url);
                    //async task goes here
                    //new PortfolioGetAllBeers(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                    PortfolioGetAllBeers task = new PortfolioGetAllBeers(c);
                    task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(useThis);
                    task.execute(url);

                }



                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    // do nothing
                }

            });



        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

but on this line:

```
    ShortBeerInfoAdapter<ShortBeerInfo> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ShortBeerInfo>(c,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tasteList );
```

I am getting shortbeerinfoadapter does not have type parameters

my short beer info adapter is:

```
public class ShortBeerInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShortBeerInfo> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<ShortBeerInfo> data = null;

    public ShortBeerInfoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<ShortBeerInfo> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        beerHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new beerHolder();
            holder.txtBeer = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.breweryName);
            holder.txtRate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.breweryRate);
            holder.txtBar = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.starbar);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (beerHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        ShortBeerInfo beer = data.get(position);
        holder.txtBeer.setText(beer.beer);
        holder.txtRate.setText(beer.rate + " out of 5.00 Stars");

        holder.numHolder= Float.parseFloat(beer.rate);

        holder.txtBar.setNumStars(5);
        holder.txtBar.setRating(holder.numHolder);

        return row;
    }

    static class beerHolder
    {
        TextView txtBeer;
        TextView txtRate;
        RatingBar txtBar;
        Float numHolder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your ShortBeerInfo, which includes the name and ID. You take the beer name, add it to a list of strings, then create the ArrayAdapter from that list. The ArrayAdapter only contains the names.

To get the ID you will need a custom array adapter of type ShortBeerInfo. You'll need to override OnCreateView in the adapter to create the View object for the list item that only contains the beer name. (Or any other beer info you may want to display)

Then in your selection listener getSelectedItem will return a ShortBeerInfo, containing the ID of the selected beer.

Comment: Can I use this array adapter I used for something else?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/74fccde80028718edbf8

Comment: changed it up but am still getting some errors, I added the new code and my adapter code to my above question under update.

Comment: The ShortBeerInfoAdapter is not a generic type. It does not need to be declared with a type because it does this as it extends from ArrayAdapter<T>. So it should be 'ShortBeerInfoAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ShortBeerInfoAdapter(c,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tasteList );'

Comment: how would i then access my shortbeerinfo object data in my onItemSelected?

Comment: portfolioType.getSelectedItem(). You may need to cast it to a ShortBeerInfo object